# How does order by work when all column values are identical?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I use SQL Server 2016. Below is the rows in table: test_account. You can see the values of `updDtm` and `fileCreateTime` are identical. `id` is the primary key.

```
id  accno   updDtm  fileCreatedTime
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   123456789   2022-07-27 09:41:10.0000000 2022-07-27 11:33:33.8300000
2   123456789   2022-07-27 09:41:10.0000000 2022-07-27 11:33:33.8300000
3   123456789   2022-07-27 09:41:10.0000000 2022-07-27 11:33:33.8300000
```

I want to query the latest account id which accno is 123456789 order by updDtm, fileCreatedTime

I run the following SQL, the output result is id = 1

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.accno ORDER BY a.updDtm desc, a.fileCreatedTime DESC) AS seq, 
         a.id, a.accno, a.updDtm, a.fileCreatedTime
     FROM 
         test_account a) AS t
WHERE t.seq = 1
```

My question is does the query result is repeatable and reliable (always output id=1 either run 1 time or multiple times) when the values of columns `updDtm` and `fileCreatedTime` are identical or just output the random id?

I read some articles and learn that for MySql and Oracle the query result is not reliable and reproducible. How about SQL Server?

Comment: No, if there is no defined order then you cannot be sure what order they will be returned.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just run the query multiple times yourself to figure this out?

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the quick reply. I just run the query over 10k times, but the output is always id=1

Comment: Based on your columns id, I believe is primary key field? Then why not we just do:
select top 1 * from yourtable Where Accno =123456, order by Id desc

, assuming any new row should always have latest largest integer id :)

Comment: @Lei, the result is not deterministic when the ORDER BY values are not unique. I wouldn't say random but rather dependent on the execution plan and other factors beyond your control. It would be best to add another column in the order by clause to break ties.

Comment: Hi  Nirmal Subedi, thanks for you reply :), I edit the question to be more clear.  Actually, my question is does the query result is repeatable and reliable when the order by columns have the same values.

Comment: I believe as long as they are same, it should be. These are machine, not human that changes. If value never change, then output should always be same.
If you want to feel assured about that then that's the reason we always add additional audit fields (like record created, updated, deleted, author, etc) apart from your transactional data.

Comment: "Just run the query...to figure it out" and presumptions that a pattern of consistent results guarantees similar results in the future are anecdotal and misleading. Unspecified behavior is just that. Tests with small data sets may tend to preserve source table insert or PK order, but the query optimizer may change the execution plan at any time based on criteria not apparent to the programmer. A plan that starts out as a clustered index scan and a loop join may change to a hash join or parallel operation, and may appear to arbitrarily reorder the results (within the ORDER BY constraints).

Comment: @T N, thanks. I'm trying to find an case to test if the query would output result other than id=1 but with no luck

Comment: @Dan Guzman, thanks for your suggestion.  How did you know the query result is not deterministic? Do you have any official document links which describe the order by behavior for this case

Comment: The problem is, small sample sizes and single queries are unlikely to *show* you that the results are non-deterministic. The closest documentation I'm aware of is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned): "To achieve stable results between query requests ... The ORDER BY clause contains a column or combination of columns that are guaranteed to be unique."

Comment: @Lei, I know the results are non-deterministic due to knowledge and experience with SQL Server, having used it for 30 years. The documentation is not always as clear as it should be so I plan to submit feedback.

Comment: @NSubedi thats not the case, the order SQL Server pulls them could be affected by statistics or changes in table structure i.e. the data doesn't change, but the order the rows are returned can change. As said by T.N. above "but the query optimizer may change the execution plan at any time based on criteria not apparent to the programmer".

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you are right, when increase the sample row count to 100000, magic happens, the query result become randomize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of [this documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) is `ORDER BY` usage with `OFFSET` and `FETCH` but the same considerations apply to all `ORDER BY` usage, including windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`. In summary,

To achieve stable results between query requests, the following conditions must be met:

1. The underlying data that is used by the query must not change.
2. The ORDER BY clause contains a column or combination of columns that are guaranteed to be unique.

> I'm trying to find an case to test if the query would output result
> other than id=1 but with no luck

The ordering of rows when duplicate `ORDER BY` values exist is undefined (a.k.a. non-deterministic and arbitrary) because it depends on the execution plan (which may vary due to available indexes, stats, and the optimizer), parallelism, database engine internals, and even physical data storage. The example below yields different results due to a parallel plan on my test instance.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test_account;
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_account(
      id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_test_account PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , accno int NOT NULL
    , updDtm datetime2 NOT NULL
    , fileCreatedTime datetime2 NOT NULL
);
--insert 100K rows
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t1g AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b CROSS JOIN t1k AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.test_account (id, accno, updDtm, fileCreatedTime)
SELECT num, 123456789, '2022-07-27 09:41:10.0000000', '2022-07-27 11:33:33.8300000'
FROM t1g
WHERE num <= 100000;
GO
--run query 10 times
SELECT t.id 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.accno ORDER BY a.updDtm desc, a.fileCreatedTime DESC) AS seq, 
         a.id, a.accno, a.updDtm, a.fileCreatedTime
     FROM 
         test_account a) AS t
WHERE t.seq = 1;
GO 10
```

Example results:

```
1
27001
25945
57071
62813
1
1
1
36450
78805
```

The simple solution is to add the primary key as the last column to the `ORDER BY` clause to break ties. This returns the same id value (1) in every iteration regardless of the execution plan and indexes.

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.accno ORDER BY a.updDtm desc, a.fileCreatedTime DESC, a.id) AS seq, 
         a.id, a.accno, a.updDtm, a.fileCreatedTime
     FROM 
         test_account a) AS t
WHERE t.seq = 1;
GO 10
```

On a side note, this index will optimize the query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.test_account(accno, updDtm DESC, fileCreatedTime DESC, id);
```

Comment: Thank you Dan for your time to explain so detail! As you said, I tried, when the sample row count increase to very large amount, for example: 100000, magic happens, the query result become randomize. I totally agree your opinion. That make sense.